# Unable to find or serve localized resource from jsf-resource-library

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, localization, resources, outputstylesheet

I am trying to replicate an example from a book,

The structure can be visualized from the image attached below-

**UPDATED**

[image]

The view for which the library will be used is as simple as this given below-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title></title>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="#{facesContext.viewRoot.locale}/default" name="css/rafa.css"/>
        <h:outputScript library="#{facesContext.viewRoot.locale}/default" name="rafa.js"/>        
    </h:head>
    <h:body>   
        <f:view locale="#{localeBean.mylocale}">     
            <div style="width:100%; text-align:center">
                <h:form>
                    <h:commandButton value="Rafa at Roland Garros" action="#{localeBean.changeLocale('fr')}"/>
                    <h:commandButton value="Rafa at Wimbledon" action="#{localeBean.changeLocale('en')}"/>
                    <h:commandButton value="Rafa at US Open" action="#{localeBean.changeLocale('us')}"/>
                    <h:commandButton value="Rafa at Australian Open" action="#{localeBean.changeLocale('au')}"/>
                </h:form>
            </div>
            <div style="width:100%; text-align:center">
                <!--<h:graphicImage library="#{facesContext.viewRoot.locale}/default" name="img/rafa.png"/> -->
                <h:graphicImage value="#{resource[facesContext.viewRoot.locale+='/default:img/rafa.png']}"/>
            </div>
        </f:view>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

with a

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class LocaleBean {

    private String mylocale = "fr";
    // getters & setters
}
```

I am using `Glassfish 4.1.1 Application Server` with `Mojarra 2.2.12` being used internally,

The `rendered HTML` is-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="j_idt2">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/glassfish-ee/javax.faces.resource/rafa.js.xhtml?ln=fr/default&amp;v=1_01_2">
        </script><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/glassfish-ee/javax.faces.resource/css/rafa.css.xhtml?ln=fr/default&amp;v=1_0" />
    </head>
    <body>     
        <div style="width:100%; text-align:center">
        <form id="j_idt8" name="j_idt8" method="post" action="/glassfish-ee/ch5/ch5_12/index.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <input type="hidden" name="j_idt8" value="j_idt8" />
            <input type="submit" name="j_idt8:j_idt9" value="Rafa at Roland Garros" />
            <input type="submit" name="j_idt8:j_idt10" value="Rafa at Wimbledon" />
            <input type="submit" name="j_idt8:j_idt11" value="Rafa at US Open" />
            <input type="submit" name="j_idt8:j_idt12" value="Rafa at Australian Open" />
            <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="---somevalue---" autocomplete="off" />
        </form>
        </div>
            <div style="width:100%; text-align:center">
                <!--&lt;h:graphicImage library="fr/default" name="img/rafa.png"/&gt; -->
                <img src="/glassfish-ee/javax.faces.resource/img/rafa.png.xhtml?ln=fr/default&amp;v=1_0" />
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The relative urls of interest in rendered html-

```
http://localhost:8080/glassfish-ee/javax.faces.resource/rafa.js.xhtml?ln=fr/default&v=1_01_2
http://localhost:8080/glassfish-ee/javax.faces.resource/css/rafa.css.xhtml?ln=fr/default&v=1_0
http://localhost:8080/glassfish-ee/javax.faces.resource/img/rafa.png.xhtml?ln=fr/default&v=1_0
```

On the console, I get this-

```
2016-06-08T20:54:52.672+0530|WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, rafa.js, from library, fr/default.
2016-06-08T20:54:52.673+0530|WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, css/rafa.css, from library, fr/default.
2016-06-08T20:54:52.717+0530|WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, img/rafa.png, from library, fr/default.
2016-06-08T20:54:57.570+0530|WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, css/rafa.css, from library, fr/default.
2016-06-08T20:56:05.587+0530|WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, img/rafa.png, from library, fr/default.
2016-06-08T20:56:09.542+0530|WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, img/rafa.png, from library, fr/default.
```

console tab of Google chrome shows-

[image]

So finally, where am I going wrong?
Please suggest.

---

After taking the help of the answer suggested below, with changes,

[image]

with an entry-

```
javax.faces.resource.localePrefix=fr
```

Accessing the page with a GET request, an alert pops up due to the following entry in `1_2.js` file depicted as `selected` in the structure attached above.

```
alert("J'ai gagnÃ© Roland Garros ...(resources/fr/1_0/css/js/rafa.js/1_2.js)");
```

[image]

I see the same alert popping-up even when after I have changed the `locale` by pressing the desired `command button`.

Why? What further needs to be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resource localization feature is pretty poorly documented in the [JSF specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsf-2_2-fr-eval-spec/index.html). On the contrary to what you'd intuitively expect, the localized subfolders won't be matched against `<f:view locale>`. Instead, they will be matched against the `<message-bundle>` entry identified with the key [`ResourceHandler.LOCALE_PREFIX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html#LOCALE_PREFIX) which has a value of [`javax.faces.resource.localePrefix`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces.application.ResourceHandler.LOCALE_PREFIX). Also, you shouldn't have the need to explicitly include `#{view.locale}` in the `library` attribute.

In order to get it to work, make sure you've declared a `<message-bundle>`  in `faces-config.xml`.

```
<application>
    <message-bundle>com.example.i18n.YourBundle</message-bundle>
</application>
```

And make sure that it has at least the below entry:

```
javax.faces.resource.localePrefix=fr
```

Then you can just reference the resources the usual way, without any mess with locale prefix and version suffix.

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="default" name="css/rafa.css" />
<h:outputScript library="default" name="rafa.js" />
```

I admit that this can be done better. When the `<message-bundle>` is not specified and/or the `javax.faces.resource.localePrefix` is absent, then it should simply fall back to the `UIViewRoot#getLocale()`. Nonetheless, this is certainly one of the rarest used JSF features. I frankly never tried it until today and I don't think I would ever use it in a real world application.

Comment: You need to specify the desired resource locale prefix as `javax.faces.resource.localePrefix` in the locale-specific message bundle. Thus e.g. `messages.properties` has value of `fr`, `messages_en.properties` has value of `en`, etc.

Comment: @BalusC Do I have to put `javax.faces.resource.localePrefix=en` in the messages_en.properties ? Why does only `<application>
  <message-bundle>messages</message-bundle><locale-config<default-locale>en</default-locale><supported-locale>en</supported-locale></locale-config></application>` work? If I don't put  `javax.faces.resource.localePrefix=en` explicitly in the file I get `
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key javax.faces.resource.localePrefix` (JSF 2.2.18)